# Update Fedora 25 to Fedora 26

Tags: fedora, update

I am trying to update Fedora 25 to Feroda 26. I am becoming this error:

```
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libzip.so.5.0.0 from install of libzip-1.3.0-1.fc26.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libzip5-1.3.0-1.fc25.remi.x86_64
```

Comment: My guess: You first have to switch back all packages from the Remi repo back to the stock variants. AFAIK, upgrading is really only supported if you don't use 3rd party repos. So, go back to stock, disable the Remi repo and try again.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: This should work, as libzip-1.5.1 in remi for F26 have the proper obsoletes for libzip5 <= 1.5.1, of course this don't work the the repository is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed all Remi repos and everything works.